# Denormalize tab-delimited text file

Tags: python

I've got a tab-delimited text file set up similarly to the one row below, where some columns have multiple values delimited with a pipe.

> 1234  PreferredName   Property1a  Property2a|Property2b|Property2c  Synonym1|Synonym2

I need a script to denormalize this as follows:

> 1234  PreferredName   Property1a   Property2a   Synonym 1
>
> 1234  PreferredName   Property1a   Property2b   Synonym 2
>
> 1234  PreferredName   Property1a   Property2c   Synonym 1

There can be no nulls, but the order of the fill-in values doesn't matter.  For instance, in row 3, column 5 above, either Synonym 1 or Synonym 2 would be an appropriate value.

Comment: Is there a problem with the script you wrote that we can help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've gotten the text into a string `s`:

```
s2=""     
L=s.split(" ")
for x in L:
   i=x.find("|")
   s2+=x[:i]+" "
print s2
```

That should denormalize one line.
Doing that for each line in the file should give you all the desired strings, which you can then write to a new file, or store in a string.

For a file:

```
result=""
f=open('file.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()
for s in lines:
   L=s.split(" ")
   for x in L:
      i=x.find("|")
      if i!=-1:
         result+=x[:i]+" "
      else:
         result+=x.strip("\n")+" "
   result=result[:-1]+"\n"
```

You should end up with a single string containing the denormalized file.
If you'd then like to write that to a new file:

```
f=f.open('newfile.txt','w')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

Comment: This only gives me the first new denormalized row, but not the remaining new denormalized rows, any ideas?

Comment: I edited.  Is this closer to what you were looking for?